# How to keep variable in html from controller?

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net-mvc

There is a controller in my projects

```
public ActionResult Create(int PeriodID = 0)
    {

        var ParentQry = from d in db.Periods
                        join sc in db.MultiRaterSurveyPeriods on d.PeriodID equals sc.PeriodID
                        where d.StartDate < DateTime.Now && d.EndDate > DateTime.Now && sc.StartDate < DateTime.Now && sc.EndDate > DateTime.Now
                        orderby d.PeriodID
                        select new {PeriodID = sc.MultiRaterSurveyPeriodID, PeriodName = d.PeriodName };

        var GroupResp = from d in db.MultiRaterSurveyGroups
                        join sc in db.RelationBetweenMRSPeriodMRSGroups on d.MultiRaterSurveyGroupID equals sc.MultiRaterSurveyGroupID
                        where d.StartDate < DateTime.Now && d.EndDate > DateTime.Now && sc.StartDate < DateTime.Now && sc.EndDate > DateTime.Now
                        orderby d.MultiRaterSurveyGroupID
                        select new { MultiRaterSurveyGroupID = d.MultiRaterSurveyGroupID, MultiRaterSurveyGroupName = d.MultiRaterSurveyGroupName, MultiRaterSurveyPeriodID = sc.MultiRaterSurveyPeriodID };

        ViewBag.PeriodID = new SelectList(ParentQry, "PeriodID", "PeriodName");
        ViewBag.surveygroups = new SelectList(GroupResp, "MultiRaterSurveyGroupID", "MultiRaterSurveyGroupName");}
```

How to get variable from controller to put in view create.cshtml for ViewBag.surveyperiod?

```
@foreach (var p in ViewBag.surveygroups)
                    {           
                                <input type="hidden" class="hiddenSurveyGroups" name="hiddenSurveyGroups" id="surveygroups" value="@ViewBag.surveygroups">
                    }
```

Because i want that value to get for javascript.

Comment: What value are you trying to retrieve? Because surveygroups is a SelectList which looks like you're trying to iterate through.

Comment: ya, from surveygroups i want to retrieve value MultiRaterSurveyGroupID.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use p.Text and p.Value for ViewBag.surveygroups. By this you can access this.

In your case you can replace `value="@ViewBag.surveygroups"` to `value="@p.Value"`

Comment: thanks ya, and once more, could you tell me how to get value to javascript, It should be name or value which to be set? 

for example:

$(groupname).empty().append($('<select id="surveygroups" name="surveygroups"><option value="0" selected="selected">----- select -----</option><option value="' + (what value?) + '"</option></select>'));

or do you have any idea? :)

Comment: You can take whatever value to be set as Hidden field in that foreach loop then you can use it as 
$(groupname).empty().append($('<select id="surveygroups" name="surveygroups"><option value="0" selected="selected">----- select -----</option><option value="' + $("#yourhiddenFieldId").val() + '"</option></select>'));